# Parse This Custom Twitter Capture Data With Python and Create Statistics

Tags: python, json, twitter, csv

I'm trying to gather Twitter statistics from a specific dataset that was provided to me. I have no control over how the data is formatted before it is given to me so I'm locked into this messy for.

I would like some suggestions on how I can build a python program to parse this sort of input and outputting something more along the lines of a CSV file with the field titles as header and the values below.

I want to use python because eventually I would like to use some statistical tools that I've already put together.

Additionally the output of a CSV type format is preferred because I may input it into something like SPSS for statistical verification.

Here's a sample of what a single post looks like from the dataset:

```
{"text":"A gente todos os dias arruma os cabelos: por que não o coração?","contributors":null,"geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":50270714498002945,"source":"web","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Tue Mar 22 19:00:46 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"50270714498002945","place":null,"user":{"location":"Brasil, Recife-PE","statuses_count":16,"profile_background_tile":true,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"867c5f","id":59154474,"following":null,"favourites_count":0,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"91957f","verified":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"description":"","profile_sidebar_border_color":"eae2bc","name":"Natalia Aráujo","profile_background_color":"eae2bc","created_at":"Wed Jul 22 15:27:15 +0000 2009","followers_count":10,"geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/220796682/music-2.png","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":-10800,"time_zone":"Brasilia","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":18,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"eae2bc","screen_name":"nat_araujo","id_str":"59154474","show_all_inline_media":false,"profile_image_url":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1247378890/154254_normal.JPG","listed_count":1,"is_translator":false},"coordinates":null}
```

The dataset is one continuous line with NO line returns between posts. The only delimiter between the actual posts is:

All posts start with

```
{"text":
```

and end with

```
null}
```

of course would be glad to share my results with everyone.

---

Based on what everyone is saying I've started off with the following:

```py
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'To Use: twitterjson2cvs.py (path/filename)'
    sys.exit()

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1])

jsondatain = json.load(inputfile)
pprint(jsondatain)

inputfile.close()
```

which outputs something a bit cleaner in the form of:

```json
{u'contributors': None,
 u'coordinates': None,
 u'created_at': u'Tue Mar 22 19:00:46 +0000 2011',
 u'entities': {u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [], u'user_mentions': []},
 u'favorited': False,
 u'geo': None,
 u'id': 50270714498002945L,
 u'id_str': u'50270714498002945',
 u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None,
 u'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
 u'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
 u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
 u'place': None,
 u'retweet_count': 0,
 u'retweeted': False,
 u'source': u'web',
 u'text': u'A gente todos os dias arruma os cabelos: por que n\xe3o o cora\xe7\xe3o?',
 u'truncated': False,
 u'user': {u'contributors_enabled': False,
           u'created_at': u'Wed Jul 22 15:27:15 +0000 2009',
           u'description': u'',
           u'favourites_count': 0,
           u'follow_request_sent': None,
           u'followers_count': 10,
           u'following': None,
           u'friends_count': 18,
           u'geo_enabled': False,
           u'id': 59154474,
           u'id_str': u'59154474',
           u'is_translator': False,
           u'lang': u'en',
           u'listed_count': 1,
           u'location': u'Brasil, Recife-PE',
           u'name': u'Natalia Ar\xe1ujo',
           u'notifications': None,
           u'profile_background_color': u'eae2bc',
           u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/220796682/music-2.png',
           u'profile_background_tile': True,
           u'profile_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1247378890/154254_normal.JPG',
           u'profile_link_color': u'867c5f',
           u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'eae2bc',
           u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'eae2bc',
           u'profile_text_color': u'91957f',
           u'profile_use_background_image': True,
           u'protected': False,
           u'screen_name': u'nat_araujo',
           u'show_all_inline_media': False,
           u'statuses_count': 16,
           u'time_zone': u'Brasilia',
           u'url': None,
           u'utc_offset': -10800,
           u'verified': False}
```

I've added to the previous code in an attempt to output to a CSV file:

```py
import sys
import json
#from pprint import pprint
import csv

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'To Use: twitterjson2cvs.py (path/filename)'
    sys.exit()

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1])

jsondatain = json.load(inputfile)

f=csv.writer(open("test.csv","wb+"))

f.writerow(["contributors","coordinates","created_at","entities","hashtags","urls","user_mentions","favorited","geo","id","id_str","in_reply_to_screen_name","in_reply_to_status_id","in_reply_to_status_id_str","in_reply_to_user_id","in_reply_to_user_id_str","place","retweet_count","retweeted","source","text","truncated","user","contributors_enabled","created_at","description","favourites_count","follow_request_sent","followers_count","following","friends_count","geo_enabled","id","id_str","is_translator","lang","listed_count","location","name","notifications","profile_background_color","profile_background_image_url","profile_background_tile","profile_image_url","profile_link_color","profile_sidebar_border_color","profile_sidebar_fill_color","profile_text_color","profile_use_background_image","protected","screen_name","show_all_inline_media","statuses_count","time_zone","url","utc_offset","verified"])
for x in jsondatain:
    f.writerow([x["contributors"],x["fields"]["coordinates"],x["fields"]["created_at"],x["fields"]["entities"],x["fields"]["hashtags"],x["fields"]["urls"],x["fields"]["user_mentions"],x["fields"]["favorited"],x["fields"]["geo"],x["fields"]["id"],x["fields"]["id_str"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_screen_name"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_status_id"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_status_id_str"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_user_id"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_user_id_str"],x["fields"]["place"],x["fields"]["retweet_count"],x["fields"]["retweeted"],x["fields"]["source"],x["fields"]["text"],x["fields"]["truncated"],x["fields"]["user"],x["fields"]["contributors_enabled"],x["fields"]["created_at"],x["fields"]["description"],x["fields"]["favourites_count"],x["fields"]["follow_request_sent"],x["fields"]["followers_count"],x["fields"]["following"],x["fields"]["friends_count"],x["fields"]["geo_enabled"],x["fields"]["id"],x["fields"]["id_str"],x["fields"]["is_translator"],x["fields"]["lang"],x["fields"]["listed_count"],x["fields"]["location"],x["fields"]["name"],x["fields"]["notifications"],x["fields"]["profile_background_color"],x["fields"]["profile_background_image_url"],x["fields"]["profile_background_tile"],x["fields"]["profile_image_url"],x["fields"]["profile_link_color"],x["fields"]["profile_sidebar_border_color"],x["fields"]["profile_sidebar_fill_color"],x["fields"]["profile_text_color"],x["fields"]["profile_use_background_image"],x["fields"]["protected"],x["fields"]["screen_name"],x["fields"]["show_all_inline_media"],x["fields"]["statuses_count"],x["fields"]["time_zone"],x["fields"]["url"],x["fields"]["utc_offset"],x["fields"]["verified"]])

#pprint(jsondatain)

inputfile.close()
```

However when I run it I get:

```
  File "twitterjson2cvs.py", line 28, in <module>
    f.writerow([x["contributors"],x["fields"]["coordinates"],x["fields"]["created_at"],x["fields"]["entities"],x["fields"]["hashtags"],x["fields"]["urls"],x["fields"]["user_mentions"],x["fields"]["favorited"],x["fields"]["geo"],x["fields"]["id"],x["fields"]["id_str"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_screen_name"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_status_id"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_status_id_str"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_user_id"],x["fields"]["in_reply_to_user_id_str"],x["fields"]["place"],x["fields"]["retweet_count"],x["fields"]["retweeted"],x["fields"]["source"],x["fields"]["text"],x["fields"]["truncated"],x["fields"]["user"],x["fields"]["contributors_enabled"],x["fields"]["created_at"],x["fields"]["description"],x["fields"]["favourites_count"],x["fields"]["follow_request_sent"],x["fields"]["followers_count"],x["fields"]["following"],x["fields"]["friends_count"],x["fields"]["geo_enabled"],x["fields"]["id"],x["fields"]["id_str"],x["fields"]["is_translator"],x["fields"]["lang"],x["fields"]["listed_count"],x["fields"]["location"],x["fields"]["name"],x["fields"]["notifications"],x["fields"]["profile_background_color"],x["fields"]["profile_background_image_url"],x["fields"]["profile_background_tile"],x["fields"]["profile_image_url"],x["fields"]["profile_link_color"],x["fields"]["profile_sidebar_border_color"],x["fields"]["profile_sidebar_fill_color"],x["fields"]["profile_text_color"],x["fields"]["profile_use_background_image"],x["fields"]["protected"],x["fields"]["screen_name"],x["fields"]["show_all_inline_media"],x["fields"]["statuses_count"],x["fields"]["time_zone"],x["fields"]["url"],x["fields"]["utc_offset"],x["fields"]["verified"]])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The error has something to do with how the formatting of the fields but I'm not seeing it.

---

I updated the code to reflect your format suggestion as follows:

```py
import sys
import json
import csv

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'To Use: twitterjson2cvs.py (path/filename)'
    sys.exit()

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1])

jsondatain = json.load(inputfile)

f=csv.writer(open("test.csv","wb+"))

f.writerow(["contributors","coordinates","created_at","entities","hashtags","urls","user_mentions","favorited","geo","id","id_str","in_reply_to_screen_name","in_reply_to_status_id","in_reply_to_status_id_str","in_reply_to_user_id","in_reply_to_user_id_str","place","retweet_count","retweeted","source","text","truncated","user","contributors_enabled","created_at","description","favourites_count","follow_request_sent","followers_count","following","friends_count","geo_enabled","id","id_str","is_translator","lang","listed_count","location","name","notifications","profile_background_color","profile_background_image_url","profile_background_tile","profile_image_url","profile_link_color","profile_sidebar_border_color","profile_sidebar_fill_color","profile_text_color","profile_use_background_image","protected","screen_name","show_all_inline_media","statuses_count","time_zone","url","utc_offset","verified"])
for x in jsondatain:
    f.writerow(
        (
            x['contributors'],
            x['coordinates'],
            x['created_at'],
            x['entities']['hashtags'],
            x['entities']['urls'],
            x['entities']['user_mentions'],
            x['favorited'],
            x['geo'],
            x['id'],
            x['id_str'],
            x['in_reply_to_screen_name'],
            x['in_reply_to_status_id'],
            x['in_reply_to_status_id_str'],
            x['in_reply_to_user_id'],
            x['in_reply_to_user_id_str'],
            x['place'],
            x['retweet_count'],
            x['retweeted'],
            x['source'],
            x['text'].encode('utf8'),
            x['truncated'],
            x['user']['contributors_enabled'],
            x['user']['created_at'],
            x['user']['description'],
            x['user']['favourites_count'],
            x['user']['follow_request_sent'],
            x['user']['followers_count'],
            x['user']['following'],
            x['user']['friends_count'],
            x['user']['geo_enabled'],
            x['user']['id'],
            x['user']['id_str'],
            x['user']['is_translator'],
            x['user']['lang'],
            x['user']['listed_count'],
            x['user']['location'],
            x['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),
            x['user']['notifications'],
            x['user']['profile_background_color'],
            x['user']['profile_background_image_url'],
            x['user']['profile_background_tile'],
            x['user']['profile_image_url'],
            x['user']['profile_link_color'],
            x['user']['profile_sidebar_border_color'],
            x['user']['profile_sidebar_fill_color'],
            x['user']['profile_text_color'],
            x['user']['profile_use_background_image'],
            x['user']['protected'],
            x['user']['screen_name'],
            x['user']['show_all_inline_media'],
            x['user']['statuses_count'],
            x['user']['time_zone'],
            x['user']['url'],
            x['user']['utc_offset'],
            x['user']['verified']
        )
    )

inputfile.close()
```

I still get the following error of:

```
twitterjson2cvs.py TweetFile1300820340639.tcm.online
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workspace/coalmine-datafilter/src/twitterjson2csv.py", line 30, in <module>
    x['contributors'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Everything is working great up to this point now for a single JSON formatted input file. The previous example JSON string input into this program:

```py
import sys
import json
import csv

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'To Use: twitterjson2cvs.py (path/filename)'
    sys.exit()

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1])

jsonindata = json.load(inputfile)

f=csv.writer(open("test.csv","wb+"))

f.writerow(["contributors","coordinates","created_at","entities","hashtags","urls","user_mentions","favorited","geo","id","id_str","in_reply_to_screen_name","in_reply_to_status_id","in_reply_to_status_id_str","in_reply_to_user_id","in_reply_to_user_id_str","place","retweet_count","retweeted","source","text","truncated","user","contributors_enabled","created_at","description","favourites_count","follow_request_sent","followers_count","following","friends_count","geo_enabled","id","id_str","is_translator","lang","listed_count","location","name","notifications","profile_background_color","profile_background_image_url","profile_background_tile","profile_image_url","profile_link_color","profile_sidebar_border_color","profile_sidebar_fill_color","profile_text_color","profile_use_background_image","protected","screen_name","show_all_inline_media","statuses_count","time_zone","url","utc_offset","verified"])

f.writerow(
        (
            jsonindata['contributors'],
            jsonindata['coordinates'],
            jsonindata['created_at'],
            jsonindata['entities']['hashtags'],
            jsonindata['entities']['urls'],
            jsonindata['entities']['user_mentions'],
            jsonindata['favorited'],
            jsonindata['geo'],
            jsonindata['id'],
            jsonindata['id_str'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_screen_name'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_status_id'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_status_id_str'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_user_id'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_user_id_str'],
            jsonindata['place'],
            jsonindata['retweet_count'],
            jsonindata['retweeted'],
            jsonindata['source'],
            jsonindata['text'].encode('utf8'),
            jsonindata['truncated'],
            jsonindata['user']['contributors_enabled'],
            jsonindata['user']['created_at'],
            jsonindata['user']['description'],
            jsonindata['user']['favourites_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['follow_request_sent'],
            jsonindata['user']['followers_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['following'],
            jsonindata['user']['friends_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['geo_enabled'],
            jsonindata['user']['id'],
            jsonindata['user']['id_str'],
            jsonindata['user']['is_translator'],
            jsonindata['user']['lang'],
            jsonindata['user']['listed_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['location'],
            jsonindata['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),
            jsonindata['user']['notifications'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_image_url'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_tile'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_image_url'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_link_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_sidebar_border_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_sidebar_fill_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_text_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_use_background_image'],
            jsonindata['user']['protected'],
            jsonindata['user']['screen_name'],
            jsonindata['user']['show_all_inline_media'],
            jsonindata['user']['statuses_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['time_zone'],
            jsonindata['user']['url'],
            jsonindata['user']['utc_offset'],
            jsonindata['user']['verified']
        )
    )

inputfile.close()
```

results in a nicely formatted output ready for tools like SPSS to use as follows:

```
contributors,coordinates,created_at,entities,hashtags,urls,user_mentions,favorited,geo,id,id_str,in_reply_to_screen_name,in_reply_to_status_id,in_reply_to_status_id_str,in_reply_to_user_id,in_reply_to_user_id_str,place,retweet_count,retweeted,source,text,truncated,user,contributors_enabled,created_at,description,favourites_count,follow_request_sent,followers_count,following,friends_count,geo_enabled,id,id_str,is_translator,lang,listed_count,location,name,notifications,profile_background_color,profile_background_image_url,profile_background_tile,profile_image_url,profile_link_color,profile_sidebar_border_color,profile_sidebar_fill_color,profile_text_color,profile_use_background_image,protected,screen_name,show_all_inline_media,statuses_count,time_zone,url,utc_offset,verified
,,Tue Mar 22 19:00:46 +0000 2011,[],[],[],False,,50270714498002945,50270714498002945,,,,,,,0,False,web,A gente todos os dias arruma os cabelos: por que não o coração?,False,False,Wed Jul 22 15:27:15 +0000 2009,,0,,10,,18,False,59154474,59154474,False,en,1,"Brasil, Recife-PE",Natalia Aráujo,,eae2bc,http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/220796682/music-2.png,True,http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1247378890/154254_normal.JPG,867c5f,eae2bc,eae2bc,91957f,True,False,nat_araujo,False,16,Brasilia,,-10800,False
```

Now the only problem is that my I have input files that have multiple JSON strings inline with each other all on one continuous line. When I attempt to run the same program on those files I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workspace/coalmine-datafilter/src/twitterjson2cvs.py", line 22, in <module>
    jsonindata = json.load(inputfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 267, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 322, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 1514 - line 2 column 1 (char 1514 - 2427042)
```

The input file is very large, (ie: multiple thousands of Twitter posts), I don't know if the error is due to the number of posts or if it's because the file has multiple `{"...."}{"...."}` all on the same line. Do I perhaps need to add a line return somehow after each feed?

Comment: @user672387: Following your update, what is your expected output?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Expected output should be stats on Location based on ('Location') correlated with ('time_zone') just for good measure. Then message ('text'), and message entropy. Then cluster analysis using entropy, time, location, etc.

Comment: @securemindorg: That information will come out of the tools that you say you have already written. I don't understand what your question is now.

Comment: no question, I was just stating that point. I'm working on a solution now to take the input json file now and output it as a csv with the data-analysis all done at the same time. I'll share when I'm done.

Comment: No question? Please take another look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @securemindorg: I've updated my answer following your latest issue. Any further problems should probably be added as new questions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should get you started...you will need to take care of the nested objects

```
import json
import csv
f = file('test.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)
#result = []
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    print k,v
    #result.append(v)
f = file('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

The input here is JSON. Python has a [JSON module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). Happily it has a [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) too. So that's your input and output taken care of!

### Update

You are getting there!

Your call to [`writerow()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) needs to look more like (not in a `for`-loop):

```
f.writerow( 
        (
            jsonindata['contributors'],
            jsonindata['coordinates'],
            jsonindata['created_at'],
            jsonindata['entities']['hashtags'],
            jsonindata['entities']['urls'],
            jsonindata['entities']['user_mentions'],
            jsonindata['favorited'],
            jsonindata['geo'],
            jsonindata['id'],
            jsonindata['id_str'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_screen_name'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_status_id'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_status_id_str'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_user_id'],
            jsonindata['in_reply_to_user_id_str'],
            jsonindata['place'],
            jsonindata['retweet_count'],
            jsonindata['retweeted'],
            jsonindata['source'],
            jsonindata['text'].encode('utf8'),
            jsonindata['truncated'],
            jsonindata['user']['contributors_enabled'],
            jsonindata['user']['created_at'],
            jsonindata['user']['description'],
            jsonindata['user']['favourites_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['follow_request_sent'],
            jsonindata['user']['followers_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['following'],
            jsonindata['user']['friends_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['geo_enabled'],
            jsonindata['user']['id'],
            jsonindata['user']['id_str'],
            jsonindata['user']['is_translator'],
            jsonindata['user']['lang'],
            jsonindata['user']['listed_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['location'],
            jsonindata['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),
            jsonindata['user']['notifications'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_image_url'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_background_tile'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_image_url'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_link_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_sidebar_border_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_sidebar_fill_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_text_color'],
            jsonindata['user']['profile_use_background_image'],
            jsonindata['user']['protected'],
            jsonindata['user']['screen_name'],
            jsonindata['user']['show_all_inline_media'],
            jsonindata['user']['statuses_count'],
            jsonindata['user']['time_zone'],
            jsonindata['user']['url'],
            jsonindata['user']['utc_offset'],
            jsonindata['user']['verified']
        )
    )
```

Also consider using [`DictWriter`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), but remember that [Python's CSV module deals badly with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650639/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-for-csv-file), hence `.encode('utf8')` on a couple of elements of the tuple.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick response. I'm not well versed in programming by any means, statistics is more my thing. However, yes I see you're right it is JSON, and I do see that there is a CSV module. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've edited my previous post, I'm still getting the "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error.

Comment: @securemindorg: Ah yes... you're trying to index into strings. I've updated my answer to make it clearer. No `for`-loop required.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, It makes much more sense now. I only have one last issue as described in the above edit. I'm having trouble when I try running it on a large file with multiple json formatted twitter posts all on the same line.

Comment: @Securemindorg: Now you are trying to read multiple JSON objects in one call. I suspect that this is not your last error, since you have no error-handling. The scope of your question has changed since you asked "how do I read and write csv?", which is a little unfair. Please try to solve these problems yourself and then ask them as new questions on StackOverflow if you can't overcome them