# Python - SQLite to CSV Writer Error - ASCII values not parsed

Tags: python, unicode, csv, sqlite

Afternoon,

I am having some trouble with a SQLite to CSV python script. I have searched high and I have searched low for an answer but none have worked for me, or I am having a problem with my syntax.

I want to replace characters within the SQLite database which fall outside of the ASCII table (larger than 128).

Here is the script I have been using:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
import sqlite3
import csv, codecs, cStringIO

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f", 
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# Select whichever rows you want in whatever order you like
c.execute('select ROWID, Name, Type, PID from PID')

writer = UnicodeWriter(open("ProductListing.csv", "wb"))

# Make sure the list of column headers you pass in are in the same order as your SELECT
writer.writerow(["ROWID", "Product Name", "Product Type", "PID", ])
writer.writerows(c)
```

I have tried to add the 'replace' as indicated here but have got the same error. [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors for CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650639/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-for-csv-file)

The error is the UnicodeDecodeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQLite2CSV1.py", line 53, in <module>
    writer.writerows(c)
  File "SQLite2CSV1.py", line 32, in writerows
    self.writerow(row)
  File "SQLite2CSV1.py", line 19, in writerow
    self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Obviously I want the code to be robust enough that if it encounters characters outside of these bounds that it replaces it with a character such as '?' (\x3f).

Is there a way to do this within the UnicodeWriter class? And a way I can make the code robust that it won't produce these errors.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to write an ASCII CSV, simply use the stock `csv.writer()`. To ensure that all values passed are indeed ASCII, use `encode('ascii', errors='replace')`.

Example:

```
import csv

rows = [
  [u'some', u'other', u'more'],
  [u'umlaut:\u00fd', u'euro sign:\u20ac', '']
]

with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'wb') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for row in rows:
        asciifiedRow = [item.encode('ascii', errors='replace') for item in row]
        print '%r --> %r' % (row, asciifiedRow)
        writer.writerow(asciifiedRow)
```

The console output for this is:

```
[u'some', u'other', u'more'] --> ['some', 'other', 'more']
[u'umlaut:\xfd', u'euro sign:\u20ac', ''] --> ['umlaut:?', 'euro sign:?', '']
```

The resulting CSV file contains:

```
some,other,more
umlaut:?,euro sign:?,
```

Comment: +1 spot on. Also note that UTF-8 isn't ASCII, so attempting to feed a UTF-8 string to a function that expects ASCII will usually have hilarious, unintended results (of which a `UnicodeEncodeError` is the most obvious - some effects are more subtle.)

Answer (score 0):

With access to a unix environment, here's what worked for me

```
sqlite3.exe a.db .dump > a.sql;
tr -d "[\\200-\\377]" < a.sql > clean.sql;
sqlite3.exe clean.db < clean.sql;
```

(It's not a python solution, but maybe it will help someone else due to its brevity.  This solution STRIPS OUT all non ascii characters, doesn't try to replace them.)