# Unicode Error on Python

Tags: python, csv, unicode

So I'm trying to make a table with a csv table that has unicode characters in it:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    [writer.writerow(r) for r in table]
```

I get this error every time i try to run my program, though:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If python 3, did you try openning the file in the enoding in which your `row` is with `encoding='<encoding>'` argument to `open()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors for CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650639/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-for-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python2:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for r in table:
        writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in r])
```

Of course, when you open the csv file, you will also need to decode it using the same encoding:

```
with open('test1.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile.decode('utf-8'))
```

(NB: if you used Python3, none of this would be necessary - your original example would work fine as it is).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need to use a list comprehension for write in csv file, secondly if you are using `python 2.X` you can use `codecs` module to open your file with a proper encoding and if you are using python 3.X you can use `encoding` argument in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

Also note that since the `write` method used your default encoding if still you got unicode error you can use `str.encode()` method in `write` method.

Python 2.X:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     for r in table:
         writer.writerow(r.encode('utf-8'))
```

Python 3.X :

```
with open(filename, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     for r in table:
         writer.writerow(r.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I get this error when I use your code:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I'm getting this error now: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @K.B Is your table contains lists?

Comment: Yeah, the element table is full of lists